# cancel submit at server

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I wanted to submit a form to the server, in order to run some server-side code. By using a form, it is a lot easier to harvest the variables in the form, instead of harvesting a bunch of fields by hand with Javascript.
But, I don't want the page to refresh or redirect. I would like to be able to return some Javascript that lets the page signal the outcome of the server-side code.
In short, an xmlHttp request that includes all the fields from the form.
Is that possible?

Comment: If you use jQuery, you can use `$("#formID").serialize()` to get all the form fields, to include in the AJAX submission. There's also an AJAX Form plugin that simplifies it all for you.

Comment: If you don't use jQuery, you can write a loop that gets all the form fields, instead of having to code each of them by hand.

Comment: You can't do this on the server. Ordinary form submission always triggers a page reload. There's nothing the server can send to stop it, because it's too late.

Comment: I think the answers are a little different than what I asked, but that's fine, because they do what I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use XMLHttpRequest object to send the requests to the server. Feel free to learn it from MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Secondly, to stop the page refresh of redirect, you can use this code

```
event.preventDefault();
```

..this will stop the page from loading etc but still it will send the request to the page you're trying to access.

#### Example code

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="someName" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sendData()" />
</form>
```

..in the JavaScript write

```
function sendData() {
   // at the top of the code
   event.preventDefault();
   // execute the XMLHttpRequest here 
}
```

#### My Recommendation

I would recommend that you use jQuery for this. jQuery is same as JavaScript as it is a library built right on JavaScript, it will minimize the long code you're going to write.

Learn it here, [jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

In jQuery it is as easy as

```
function sendData() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'page.html',
      // as barmar has suggested in comments
      data: $("#formID").serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        alert('Message from server' + data);
      }
   });
}
```

The above code would send the request, and you will get the results in the success function's `data` object.

Comment: This wasn't what his question was asking about.

Comment: @Barmar, i thought he was asking for a _yes/no_ about the task :)